# Can't create table from postgresql through sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I try to create a table in postgresql through sqlalchemy in python. The coding executes without returning any error but the table just can't be created. Below is the code and I really appreciate some help. Thank you!

```py
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

DATABASE_URL = "postgres://wzmsxnmxhimb....."

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))

db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE books (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,isbn INTEGER NOT NULL,title VARCHAR NOT NULL,author VARCHAR NOT NULL,year INTEGER NOT NULL)")
    db.commit
    print ("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It should not execute without an error, since the name `name` has not been defined.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Your `main()` is never executed because your if statement is never met. Try changing to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

also your quotations use `DATABASE_URL` as a string and not you variable, change this line to the following:

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv(DATABASE_URL))
```

if problem persists add a `try/except` to your `main()` to see the result:

```
def main():
    try:
        db.execute("CREATE TABLE books (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,isbn INTEGER NOT NULL,title VARCHAR NOT NULL,author VARCHAR NOT NULL,year INTEGER NOT NULL)")
        db.commit
        print ("done")
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Comment: Thanks ! run the file again and got the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create.py", line 7, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
  File "C:\Users\green\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: second half - File "C:\Users\green\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 56, in create
    plugins = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'

Comment: I use set DATABASE_URL=postgres://wzm... in command prompt, deleted DATABASE_URL as string part in .py and  run the .py again. Like before, everything goes through and return a "done" but no table is created.

Comment: @Cheryl add a try/except to see what the db returns like above.

Comment: Try the above code and it returns "done". Does it mean the connection to db established successfully?

Comment: So are you sure you are watching the correct schema? Because your code seems to be working.

Comment: I think so, I installed python 7 on win10, sqlalchemy, pip, flask are all latest version. Postgresql is not installed on local but remote server on Heroku. I am using VS code and install their python extension. I might try to uninstall and reinstall everything again.

Comment: One thing that I want to point out is, I can't just flask run on command line. Besides, setting the environment variable such as DATABASE_URL, FLASK_APP, I need to create an virtual env to run the flask. I am not sure if it has anything to do with my current db issue.

Comment: Then you may be running your code with a different version which has not flask installed

Comment: Hi, I have successfully created a table via my code today. I have reinstalled everything a few times , now I am using ubuntu install of window cmd. And the code ran throught as I used notepad to edit code instead of VS code. I am not sure if it is the reason. But the problem solved at this setting anyway.